# Why does my Wavelet transformed data got more entries as my input data?

Tags: python, wavelet-transform, open-bci

I use the Brainflow library to perform a wavelet transformation on the OpenBCI's data. I noticed that after the wavelet transformation the data always increases.

What is the reason for this?
Is there a way to keep the shape the same?

I would give the data to a neural network after the wavelet transformation. The batch size is 375. the input data is always divisible by 375 (22500/375=60), but after the wavelet transformation it is no longer divisible.

I have tested different data but the shape always changed.

Example:
input shape before transformation: (16, 22500) / (16, 7125) / (16, 22125)
after Wavelet transformation:      (16, 22525) / (16, 7151) / (16, 22151)